# Function Parameters Type as Object

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

In typescript, the `Parameters<T>` utility type returns a tuple. How would I get the same thing but as an object?

```js
type Idk<T> = //...

declare function createUser(id: string, userType: UserEnum): Option<User>;

// [id: string, userType: UserEnum]
let params: Parameters<typeof createUser>;

// {id: string, userType: UserEnum}
let paramsObj: Idk<typeof createUser>;
```

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: What would that even mean? JavaScript doesn't have named parameters, only positional ones.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for more information; basically the answer is either "no" or "you can only do it if you manually map parameter positions to property names like `SomeType<typeof createUser, ["id", "userType"]>`" (which is a long way of saying "no" unfortunately)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, clarifying that the labels on the tuple are cosmetic is very helpful.